# I cannot add the new App even if i have a role of the App Manager in the itunes

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I Previously do not have the correct role to add the new App in the itunes but now I have the App Manager role even if i cannot able to create it.
Here is the reference link which i follow but it also does not help to solve the Problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96532

Comment: have you created certificate of app ?

Comment: Yes I have created certificate , distribution and even i have made the ipa

Comment: when you click on "+" icon and select new app for create. what should be the error from itunes apple ?

Comment: or you can't click on "+" icon as its disable.

Comment: I can click but it redirects me to the main page. I have the same issue as this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96532 but  issue cannot resolved by own as this link said

Comment: maybe some itunes issue. wait sometime and try later. you can report also.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of the Apple itunes. Finally after 4-5 hours i manage to create the new app.